Texture is not even on UV mapped material
I have applied a texture on my object. In some parts of the object, the material is not equally applied. I have UV unwrapped it, also applied all transformations on my object.

As seen where the Red selection is, the noise seems stretched at that spot, whereas the other noise is the same on other parts of the object.

In the shadings tab, I have applied same scale for the object, and in the Blue selection it looks different.

What output are you using in the Texture Coordinate node? If you use Generated, switch to Object. If it still doesn't work, please share your file

By default it was Normal, switching to Object fixed the issue! Thank you!!!

By switching to object you basically no longer have the UV unwrap working. If you want to use your UVs, you should check stretching with a UV checker before the actual texture

Switch the Texture Coordinate output to Object. It will project an unstretched noise onto the surface, while Normal (or Generated) will deform it.
